# Docker stack to Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, yaml, docker-compose, docker-stack

I am quite familiar with Docker, but I have zero experience on Kubernetes.

I have a [Docker stack](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stack/) (multi-container) software that I can deploy in a Docker swarm cluster. I was wondering if Kubernetes has something similar? I don't need replicas, auto scaling and so on... I just need a group of containers working together with its dependencies and networks defined in single text file.

I have searched and found a tool called [kompose](http://kompose.io/) that translates the Docker stack file to Kubernetes syntax... However, it looks like the output is a list of `*.yaml` files, instead of a single file.

So, I came to the conclusion that kubernetes does not have this exact functionality.. Am I missing something?

Comment: You want to have all the definitions generated in a single file. Is that right?

Comment: @AymanNedjmeddine, Yes... It would be nice...  But I am open to alternatives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy the content of the generated files into one file and separate them with `---`.

For instance, if you've got 3 Kubernetes files: `service.yml`, `deployment.yml` and `configmap.yml`, your file should look something like:

```
# content of service.yml
....
---
# content of deployment.yml
....
---
# content of configmap.yml
....
```

You would use the same `kubectl` commands to CRUD using this spec file.

Comment: Would the content of "service.yml" include the content of its dockerfile?

Comment: @guilhermecgs No. The dockerfile is used to create the Docker image, which is referenced in one of these yaml files (deployment.yml I guess). This is the same with Docker compose.

Answer (score 0):

A single 'Docker Stack' yml definition is equivalent to a collection of Kubernetes Deployments and Services. Each service in a Docker Stack definition is also available to one another via a default overlay network automatically created by docker at deploy time. To simulate this in Kubernetes you would need to define multiple deployments/services with-in the same file so that they could be created and deleted as a single 'stack'.